# Error: EROFS: read-only file system while streaming the xlsx content in Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, aws-lambda

- I am Using xlsx library to parse an excel document to get the data as
  sheet per file, row per file , column per file etc...
- While processing inside AWS lambdaI am getting the below error stack

> {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'Dist Share Summary.xlsx'","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"EROFS: read-only file system, open 'Dist Share Summary.xlsx'","code":"EROFS","errno":-30,"syscall":"open","path":"Dist Share Summary.xlsx","stack":["Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'Dist Share Summary.xlsx'","    at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)","    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1194:35)","    at write_dl (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:2593:112)","    at write_zip_type (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:20730:31)","    at writeSync (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:20818:22)","    at Object.writeFileSync (/var/task/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:20841:9)","    at workbook.SheetNames.forEach.element (/var/task/index.js:31:26)","    at Array.forEach ()","    at getParsedData (/var/task/index.js:27:32)","    at Parsing (/var/task/index.js:20:32)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'Dist Share Summary.xlsx'","    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)","    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)","    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)","    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"]}

Answer (score 1):

The Lambda file system is read only aside from /tmp - you have up to 500mb to use, don't forget to remove the file when you're don, if the container is reused the file will still be there and you'll run out of space over time.